# How to replace Log::Dispatch::File with ::FileRotate?

Tags: perl, logging

I've inherited a large app that's using [Log::Dispatch::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Dispatch::File). This sets up a `$log` object, which you call like `$log->info('You are here')`. There are thousands of calls to this object throughout this app.

We need to rotate the log files, so I started to play around with [Log::Dispatch::FileRotate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Dispatch::FileRotate). Despite being described in its docs as "basically a Log::Dispatch::File wrapper with additions", FileRotate instead sets up a `$file` object, and you log things by calling `$file->log( level => 'info', message => 'You are here' );`. This is obviously incompatible with my existing app.

Is there some easy way to get from here to a typical $log object, so that I don't have to rewrite all of these thousands of calls?

Comment: Can you show a minimal example? See [mcve]

Comment: I'm not sure what there is to show--according to its docs, L::D::FileRotate provides a different interface from L::D::File. Any MWE would simply quote the documentation.

Comment: Re "*Despite being described in its docs as "basically a Log::Dispatch::File wrapper with additions"*", It does wrap an L::D::File object, and it does provide functionality that L::D::File doesn't.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious, but L::D::FR returns a $file object, not a $log object. How do I get the $log object? It's not $file->log, unless the bit of code passing this through the system is doing something odd. (That is: right now I return $log from the setup routine; if I return $file->log, it doesn't work.)

Comment: Specifically, if I return $file->log or $file->log(), I get the error "level is a required parameter for an un-named validation subroutine" from anything that tries to use that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log::Dispatch::File does not provide an `->info` method. You are actually creating and using a Log::Dispatch object. Yes, a Log::Dispatch::File object does get created, but you aren't using it directly. You are using a Log::Dispatch object, *and you should continue to do so!*

You might be using something like the following:

```perl
my $log = Log::Dispatch->new(
    outputs => [
        [ 'File', min_level => 'debug', filename => 'logfile' ],
    ],
);
```

If so, replace it with the following:

```perl
my $log = Log::Dispatch->new(
    outputs => [
        [ 'FileRotate', min_level => 'debug', filename => 'logfile' ],
    ],
);
```

Any additional parameters you want to pass to L::D::FR (`size`, `max`, etc) can be put in the array.

You might be using something like the following:

```perl
my $log = Log::Dispatch->new();
$log->add(
    Log::Dispatch::File->new(
        name      => 'file1',
        min_level => 'debug',
        filename  => 'logfile'
    )
);
```

If so, replace it with the following:

```perl
my $log = Log::Dispatch->new();
$log->add(
    Log::Dispatch::FileRotate->new(
        name      => 'file1',
        min_level => 'debug',
        filename  => 'logfile'
    )
);
```

Comment: God, yes, that seems to be it! I was indeed using something like your first example above. Swapping in 'FileRotate', along with the specific parameters FR requires, does simply work. (Now am testing to make sure that the post_rotate callback does in fact work.) Thank you for making this so clear.

Comment: Yup, I see. The `size` parameter is working; my `post_rotate` callback isn't, but that's obviously a question of debugging my code, rather than a failure of it to be called or anything. Thanks!

Comment: I'm kinda surprised. But you might have better luck with the second usage in my post.

Comment: Oh, no, there's no actual problem here, I just wrote my callback without looking at the docs. It would make sense to me if `post_rotate` told you what the file had just been renamed to, so you can do something with it, rather than telling you the name of the new, empty file. But it's working now!

Comment: According to the example in the docs, it looks like the first argument of the callback is the name to which the log file was renamed. (And the name of the log file being written to is `$fileRotate->filename()`, where `$fileRotate` is the third argument.)

Comment: No, if the index is 0--that is, if it's the first backup it's creating--then `filename` and `$fileRotate->filename()` are the same thing, the bare name. In my case, I don't want to keep around _any_ `foo.log.1` files, I want to move the rotated file right away. So I have to reconstruct the `foo.log.1` name and then move that to `old_logs/` or whatever.

Comment: That might be a bug. At the very least, the docs could use some clearing up. And if it's not a bug, then it's a feature request for a new parameter. If you create a minimal, reproducable demonstration of the problem, I'll look into it and report it as a bug or feature request as appropriate. (Post it as a new question.)

Comment: OK @ikegami, I've created a new question at [MCVE showing Log::Dispatch::FileRotate has unexpected/poorly documented behavior in post_rotate callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64111885/mcve-showing-logdispatchfilerotate-has-unexpected-poorly-documented-behavior). Thanks for taking the time on this.