# Does Log::Dispatch::FileRotate provide the new/current name of the rotated file to the post_rotate callback?

Tags: perl, logging

I'm posting this at the suggestion of @ikegami, who helped me in [How to replace Log::Dispatch::File with ::FileRotate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64107982/how-to-replace-logdispatchfile-with-filerotate) and noted some unexpected behavior.

The main point is that Perl's `Log::Dispatch::FileRotate` automatically moves log files according to different constraints (time, size, etc.), and has a `post_rotate` callback in the constructor so you can perform actions after the file rotation is complete. This does not behave in an obvious way in what I consider to be the most obvious use case: when you don't want to create multiple backup logs called `filename.1`, `filename.2`, etc., but rather when you want to immediately move the backup somewhere else. The docs do explain that when you're dealing with the first rotated file, the `filename` passed to the callback is "the new, empty, log file", but what you probably want (at least somewhere) is the name of the just-rotated file.

Below is a MCVE showing this behavior: the `log1` actions, which would seem to be the way one "should" code this, do not work in a sensible way.

In order to get the "expected" result, you need to use the `log2` actions to recreate the name of the just-rotated file. This is not really documented, and it's not very clean to regenerate the name of the file. Is this the only way, or is there a better way of doing this?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Log::Dispatch::FileRotate;

my $rotate_size = 1_000;

##### setup code

my $file1 = "log-one.log";
my $backupdir1 = "Old1";

my $log1 = Log::Dispatch->new(
    outputs => [
    [ 'FileRotate',
      min_level => 'debug',
      mode => '>>',
      newline => 1,
      filename => $file1,
      size => $rotate_size,
      post_rotate => sub {
          my ($filename, $index, $fileRotate ) = @_;
          print "ONE: filename: [$filename]; fileRotate filename: [". $fileRotate->filename()."]\n";
          mkdir $backupdir1 unless -e $backupdir1;
          my $new_filename = $backupdir1 . "/" . $filename . "-" . time();
          rename($filename, $new_filename) or die "Can't move first logfile: $!";
          
      },
      ],
    ],
);

my $file2 = "log-two.log";
my $backupdir2 = "Old2";

my $log2 = Log::Dispatch->new(
    outputs => [
    [ 'FileRotate',
      min_level => 'debug',
      mode => '>>',
      newline => 1,
      filename => $file2,
      size => $rotate_size,
      post_rotate => sub {
          my ($filename, $index, $fileRotate ) = @_;
          print "TWO: filename: [$filename]; fileRotate filename: [". $fileRotate->filename()."]\n";
          mkdir $backupdir2 unless -e $backupdir2;
          my $old_file = $filename . ".1"; # already-rotated file
          my $new_filename = $backupdir2 . "/" . $file2 . "-" . time();
          rename($old_file, $new_filename) or die "Can't move second logfile: $!";
          
      },
      ],
    ],
);

##### We do stuff here

$log1->info("starting!");

open(my $fh, '>>', $file1) or die "Could not open file '$file1' $!\n";
print $fh "x" x $rotate_size;
close $fh;

$log1->info("finished!");

# "Sensible" result: a 1010-byte file called Old1/log-one.log-160134[etc].
# consisting of "starting!\n" plus 1,000 "x"s; a 10-byte file called test.log
# consisting of "finished!\n"
#
# Actual result: a 10-byte file called Old1/log-one.log-160134[etc], consisting
# of "finished!\n"; a 1010-byte file called log.one-log.1 consisting of "starting!\n"
# plus 1,000 "x"s.

$log2->info("starting!");

open($fh, '>>', $file2) or die "Could not open file '$file2' $!\n";
print $fh "x" x $rotate_size;
close $fh;

$log2->info("finished!");

# This is the desired result: the old, rotated log is archived as
# Old2/log-two.log-160134[etc], consisting of "starting!\n" plus 1,000 "x"s;
# the "current" log is "log-two.log", consisting of "finished!\n". But this
# requires some non-obvious stuff in post_rotate, where we have to recreate
# the filename of the just-rotated file.
```

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into the issue, and I can confirm the current name of the rotated file is not available. I have [reported](https://github.com/mschout/perl-log-dispatch-filerotate/issues/24) this issue.

In the meantime, the following workaround is available:

```perl
sub post_rotate {
   my (undef, $index, $fileRotate) = @_;

   # Current path to the rotated file.
   my $current_qfn = $fileRotate->filename() . "." . ($index+1);

   # Handle the situation where this callback is called too many times.
   return if !-e $current_qfn;

   ...
}
```

This can be used even if `max` is a greater than `1`. The check is because the callback can be called once too many when `max` is greater than 1! This was also reported in the same ticket.